# Update the Data model

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have Data Model (class) for example looking like this:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(30))
```

I have a lot of records in this table now and I want to add a field, for example to save the email address.

I have searched the documentation and have not found a recommended way to do this. I have updated my MySql manually and added the field to the model and works most of the time if I declare the fields correctly.

Is there a "Best Practice" how to do this? Does SQLAlchemy have built in support to make updates to the table definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is "*No*".

But check out [alembic](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/alembic).